# DBI ROracle function to insert into table without create privileges

Tags: r, rstudio, roracle

I have a data frame which I wish to insert into a table in an Oracle database.
When putting data into my personal schema I have no problems using

```
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = "my_table", value = "my_data_frame",
 overwrite = TRUE, date = true)
```

However I've recently been granted SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE privileges on a table outside my personal schema. My goal is to insert new data from a data frame into this table.

Using basically the same syntax as above except for specifying the schema:

```
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = "my_table", schema = "new_schema",
 value = "my_data_frame", overwrite = TRUE, date = true)
```

I run into the following error message:

```
Error in .oci.GetQuery(con, stmt) : ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

My assumption is that it is from `dbWriteTable` being structured around creating tables, which I don't have permission for. I haven't managed to find an alternative method however to accomplish what I want to do.

Any suggestions?

Note: Not sure what the applicability will be of using solutions outside the scope of DBI and ROracle, as I think I'm somewhat limited in what I can actually use within the work environment.